# How to display menu on home page instead of home page content in Joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla

I want to display Menu on Home page instead of content in Joomla 3. How to do it ?

My home page is just a kind of intro page, it has header (logo and tag line only), footer and one menu with large buttons which are linked to inner pages. So instead of home page content I want to display the menu.

Comment: Can you explain a little more on your requirement?

Comment: you need to make special menu for each content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean put an menu as the main item on a page see here:
http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F

Else consider a custom home page template?

Your question isn't particularly clear - but hope this helps!

Comment: Done, used {loadposition position-name} and added instead of content on article linked to home page. Created custom module of type menu, and loaded that custom module at the above position.

Comment: Nice one! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Done, used {loadposition position-name} and added instead of content on article linked to home page. Created custom module of type menu, and loaded that custom module at the above position.